# cross-domain.xml file: Different policies in different directories

Tags: xml, crossdomain.xml

I came across cross-domain xml files on Vimeo and found that there are different policies on different directories.
One on https://vimeo.com/settings/crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="none" secure="false"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="none" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Another on https://vimeo.com/crossdomain.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I want to know what factors will decide which policy will be prioritized? Can we say it is an overly-permissive crossdomain xml file?(seeing the first one)
Also, what does this line mean?

```
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="by-content-type" />
```